# Inheriting from an abstract class

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract

Lets assume that I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Customer {
  private int price;

  public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
  }

  public int getPrice() {
    return price;
  }

  public abstract void pay(int n);
  public abstract void occupySpace();

}
```

I also have two classes that inherit from it:

1. `HandicappedCustomer`, where I want to set the price to be 0.
2. `RegularCustomer`, where I want to set the price to be 100.

Now if I create an instance of each of these classes and called `getPrice()`, I return 0 for both. What is the easiest way to make it return 0 and 100 when I call `getPrice()` for each corresponding instance of the class?

When I try to call `setPrice(100)` inside the `RegularCustomer` class, I see that it doesn't work. To put it plainly, I want to have the following code in my main:

```
Customer a = new HandicappedCustomer(); 
Customer b = new RegularCustomer();
System.out.println(a.getPrice());
System.out.println(b.getPrice());
```

And to have it return:

> 0
>   100

Comment: show us your code, for all classes and your main.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want `getPrice` to **always** return 100 for regular customers and **always** return 0 for handicapped customers, you would write

```
class RegularCustomer extends Customer {
    public int getPrice() {
        return 100;
    }
}

class HandicappedCustomer extends Customer {
    public int getPrice() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

but that doesn't exactly sound like what you want (at least for regular customers) since you included `setPrice` in your design.  Sounds like you want those values to be returned *initially*.  In that case:

```
class RegularCustomer extends Customer {
    public RegularCustomer() {
        setPrice(100);
    }
}
```

and

```
class HandicappedCustomer extends Customer {
    public HandicappedCustomer() {
        setPrice(0);
    }
}
```

should do the trick.

They will both inherit `setPrice` in case you want to change them later, and they will both inherit `getPrice` so everything should work as expected.

[Live demo at ideone](http://ideone.com/VVSAuY).

Comment: Ugh this is a lot simpler than I thought (Feel idiotic now). Thanks. I tried calling setPrice in my HandicappedCustomer class without using a constructor, which wasn't working.

Comment: Note I had a typo in my first answer but I fixed it at added a link to a working example at ideone.  (The problem was that subclasses can only access `this.price` if `price` is made protected or package-private.  Since it is private we have to call the setter from the constructor.) Hope it helps.